# Where can I find the pet dog in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

I know you can get a dog as a pet from a junkyard in Fallout 3.  Where is the Junkyard in relation to Vault 101?

Comment: More info on **Dogmeat** the possible dog companion in Fallout 3: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dogmeat_%28Fallout_3%29

Comment: I missed the dog too when I finished Fallout 3. But I will repeat the game soon, and I want my pet ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The location is called the scrapyard, you can find it NE of Vault 101, just a little to the south of Minefield.