# Where to find a dog in Fallout 3

Tags: fallout-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find the pet dog in Fallout 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/648/where-can-i-find-the-pet-dog-in-fallout-3)

I need a dog and I dont know where to find one, please help.

Answer (score 5):

From [the vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dogmeat_%28Fallout_3%29):

> Dogmeat is found in the Scrapyard  south of Minefield fighting several raiders.